# How do I return a list of strings from a list of lists?

Tags: scheme, racket

### The homework question is the following...

(10 pts) Write a function explode that, given a list of tuples, (n x), creates a new list by inserting
x into the list n times in place of (n x) (in other words, the inserted items should come in the same
order as the original tuples when you create the new list). You can assume that n will always be at
least 0.

> (explode ‘((2 "Hello"))) produces ->("Hello" "Hello")
>
> (explode ‘((2 "Hello") (3 "world"))) produces ->("Hello" "Hello"
>   "world" "world" "world")

---

A possible solution I have thought of so far was to have a loop that would keep track of what tuple the algorithm is currently working on and then inside of that loop have a function definition that would be called recursively to add the string to the return list. But I am not sure this will work because it seems like it would require the use of 'set!' which the professor said we are not allowed to use.

I am not looking for a complete answer as this is a homework problem. I would just like to be pointed in the right direction on how to approach this problem, maybe with some sudo code.

Thanks all!

Comment: Do you know how to write a recursive `append` function? You can use that to recurse over the top-level list and combine the results from each list.

Comment: @Barmar How would you keep track of how many times you have inserted 'x' into the list to be returned because each tuple within the list could have different values for n?

Comment: You need *two* recursive functions. One deals with `(2 "Hello")` and turns it into `("Hello" "Hello")`, and another combines all of these into the final result by appending them together.

Comment: @Barmar So, maybe have two separate functions one with a loop that iterates through the main list and then every time it iterates through the list it calls the other function with parameters (n string), which returns a list back to the main function with n number of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide this into two problems:

First, write a function `expand` that works like this:

```
(expand 3 "world") => ("world" "world" "world"))
```

Second, implement `explode` so that it calls `expand` on each of its arguments, and appends the results together into a single list.

```
(explode '(x y z ...)) => 
    (append (expand (first x) (second x)) 
            (expand (first y) (second y))
            (expand (first z) (second z))
            ...)
```

Both functions can be recursive. The base case for `expand` is when the first element of the list is `0`. The base case for `explode` is when the list is empty. You need to figure out how to combine the current result with the recusive call to produce the correct result for each problem.

Comment: I don't have a great understanding of recursion, but when implementing 'expand' wouldn't it require you to set the value of 'n' to n - 1 in the tuple every time it is recused? Because my professor wont allow us to use any calls with a '!' in them.

Comment: No, you can create a new list in the recursive call: `(expand (list (- (car l) 1) (cadr l)))`

Comment: I've changed the answer so that `expand` gets more than one argument, that should simplify it.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. what does `explode` of an empty list produce?
2. what does `explode` of `'((2 "Hello") (3 "world")))` produce?
3. what does `explode` of `'((3 "world"))` produce?
4. How can you go from #3 to #2?

How can you "combine" the result of #3 (recursive call on cdr) with `'(2 "Hello")` (car of the list) to produce the result of #2?

You can **assume** that you have the result of the recursive call when constructing the "combine" function (the combine function may be recursive too).

Answer (score 0):

Try not to think about loops when using functional languages.
In general, most of the problems imperatively solved with loops, can be solved with [map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) and reduce ([foldr/foldr](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) in Racket) functions. In special cases, when these functions are not enough, you can think about recursion.
Your particular task can be solved just utilizing `map` function:

```
#lang racket
(define(explode tuples)
  (flatten
   (map
    (lambda (tuple)
      (let*
          ([repeat-n-times (range  (first tuple))]
           [value (second tuple)])
        (map (λ _ value) repeat-n-times)))
    tuples)))
```